# "The client disconnected" HttpException

Tags: .net, wcf

I have read several questions about this error, but they all have to do with ASP.NET and ViewState.  My scenario is different:

I have a WPF Windows application calling a WCF service.  Sometimes I am getting the `HttpException`: `The client disconnected`

It is random and I cannot reproduce it outside of production.

At the same time, the WPF client application throws a `TimeoutException`.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

it could happen due lots of reason. you didn't provide enough information about your code.
but consider these:
1-you didn't close the client after consuming web service.(our dispose confection in restful)
2- your wcf application isn't configure properly.
3- you have a network problem.
for more information please take a look at this:
[How to increase WCF Throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685244/how-to-increase-wcf-throttling-for-a-performance-load-test/40693820#40693820)