# How to increase WCF Throttling for a performance load test

Tags: wcf, throttling

I am preparing my WCF services for a performance load test. We need to find the system limits.

My understanding is that the default WCF throttling settings will impact performance load tests and does not allow to find the system limit.

What are the configuration settings that I need to increase and loosen up the WCF throttling settings?

So far I have the following items in mind and I wonder if they are accurate or the correct ones?

```
        <behavior name="B1">
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="20000" maxConcurrentSessions="20000" maxConcurrentInstances="20000"/>
        </behavior>
```

Answer (score 1):

never forgot to set max connection property:

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="500" />
</connectionManagement>
```

the default value is 2. for more information you can read this: [scale up WCF service](https://codewala.net/2014/10/14/simple-steps-scale-up-wcf-drastically/)